# Logging response body BEFORE compression in ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, middleware

I have a seemingly simple thing that I need to do; log the response body from middleware AFTER it has been fully formed by controllers but BEFORE compression is applied.

The problem here is that I am only able to read a response after awaiting next() from the logging middleware, which also compresses the response body.

My logging implementation is based on this article;
https://elanderson.net/2019/12/log-requests-and-responses-in-asp-net-core-3/?unapproved=220252&moderation-hash=337bbb1489547696340e7506459779ba#comment-220252

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
...
    app.UseMiddleware<RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware>();

    app.UseRouting();

    //compression
    app.UseResponseCompression();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });

    ConfigurePSTZone();
...
}
```

RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware middleware;

```
    var originalBodyStream = context.Response.Body;
    await using var responseBody = _recyclableMemoryStreamManager.GetStream();
    context.Response.Body = responseBody;
    await _next(context); 
    context.Response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    var responseBody = await new StreamReader(context.Response.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
```

If you call **await _next(context);** then responseBody will be filled with the compressed response after. If you dont call it, responseBody will be empty. Even if you move the **UseMiddleware();** to the very end of Configure.

Not sure there is actually a solution for this currently in .Net 5, but hey maybe someone has figured it out.

Thanks

**ADDED NOTE:** This seems to only be a problem when using Asp.Net with kestrel (linux based). On windows you dont need response compression middleware.. so I guess not a lot of people have switched to Linux yet which is why nobody has asked this question before. Jeepers

Answer (score 0):

Middlewares are executed in order ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#middleware-order)).
You can move `app.UseMiddleware<RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware>();` call after `app.UseResponseCompression();`

Comment: Moving it after compression means the response will be compressed.

Comment: Ran into the same issue, and I'm on Windows. Guess we need to open a bug as it clearly executes response compression before the middleware. I don't suppose you have a repro sample handy..

Comment: @PaulNel No, to log the response in clear text you'll need to put it after the compression middleware. Quote from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#middleware-order: The order that middleware components are added in the Program.cs file defines the order in which the middleware components are invoked on requests and **the reverse order for the response**.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue while using the .net core inbuilt ResponseCompression, but was able to use the inspiration from [CompressionMiddleware.cs](https://gist.github.com/AndreiGorlov/388745f59145209fa951) to create a custom compression middleware

And Configure in Startup.cs is as follows

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        app.UseCompression();
        
        app.UseMiddleware<RequestResponseLogger>();
```